# Location of datastax opscenter dashboards

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

Just a simple question: where does datastax opscenter store it`s dashboards? Is it stored in the opscenter keyspace or as file on the filesystem? Could not find anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpsCenter currently stores the configuration for dashboards in the OpsCenter keyspace, specifically in the settings table.